# SVG-defined backdrop-filter doesn’t render on Safari/Chrome

Tags: css, svg, firefox, safari, cross-browser

Consider the following example (adapted from [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backdrop-filter/)), which applies the same `feTurbulence`/`feDisplacementMap` SVG filter to two HTML elements, one as a CSS `filter()` and one as a CSS `backdrop-filter()`. On Chrome, the distortion is applied correctly to both elements, but on Firefox/Safari only the element using `filter()` is distorted, while the element using `backdrop-filter()` is unaffected.

```css
.modal {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  backdrop-filter: url(#filter-turbulence);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.modal p:last-child {
  filter: url(#filter-turbulence);
}

/* misc. irrelevant styles for demo */
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; } body { background-image: url('https://41.media.tumblr.com/efd15be8d41b12a7b0ef17fba27c3e20/tumblr_mqqy59HMaf1qzattso1_1280.jpg'); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; } .container { align-items: center; display: flex; justify-content: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; } a { color: #bf0222; }
```

```html
<svg height="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter-turbulence">
      <feTurbulence
        type="turbulence"
        baseFrequency="0.01"
        numOctaves="4"
        result="turbulence"
      />
      <feDisplacementMap
        in2="turbulence"
        in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="30"
        xChannelSelector="R"
        yChannelSelector="G"
      />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="container">
  <div class="modal">
    <p>The background behind these paragraphs uses a SVG filter with backdrop-filter(). The background behind it should be distorted.</p>
    <p>This paragraph uses a SVG filter with filter(). The text should be distorted.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I’ve been having trouble debugging this issue since Safari and Firefox *do* accept the filter in `filter()`, just not in `backdrop-filter()`, and since no error messages are produced on either browser in the console or in the CSS inspector.

I’ve tried simpler SVG filters to verify that Chrome and Safari *do* support SVG backdrop-filters: simple effects like blur/desaturate work properly. However, I’ve been unable to get any combination of `feTurbulence` and/or `feDisplacement` to render in a backdrop-filter in either browser.

Is there some obvious way I’m mis-defining my filters that Chromium tolerates but other browsers do not? Is there some known limitation in other browsers’ backdrop-filter implementations that I’ve been unable to find documented?

Comment: AFAIK, backdrop-filter doesn't support SVG filter urls in Firefox and Safari. I'm actually surprised to see that they work in Chrome.

Comment: @MichaelMullany Note that Firefox *does* support SVG backdrop-filters for some simple values, e.g. Firefox can successfully apply the following a SVG filter as a backdrop-filter `<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" in="SourceGraphic" /> <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0.0" />` (applies blur and grayscale to the backdrop content)

Comment: My guess then, Luke, is that there is SVG support for whatever is equivalent to the "native" CSS filter functions aka. blur(), saturate() invert() etc. But @RobertLongson would be the expert on Firefox mechanics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox backdrop-filter is only supported in the graphics path called webrender.

Unfortunately webrender currently only supports CSS filters but if we can define an SVG filter chain in terms of CSS filters (together with some other clipping restrictions) then we can do backdrop-filtering with SVG (and CSS filters). If we can't then we give up.

So the presence of a filter element such as feComponentTransfer that has no CSS filter equivalent causes the whole backdrop-filter to fail. But a filter such as feGaussianBlur that we can convert to blur() is OK.

At some point I imagine we'll extend the scope of webrender to implement more SVG filters.